# Why is return value from "async Task" method not Task

Tags: c#

Why is this working? Return type is NOT Task.

```
public async Task<WorkItem> CreateWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
{
    WorkItem item = new WorkItem();
    workItem.Description = "something";
    item = await Task.FromResult(item);
    return item;
}
```

Why is this not working? Return type is Task.

```
public async Task<WorkItem> CreateWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
{
    WorkItem item = new WorkItem();
    workItem.Description = "something";
    Task<WorkItem> result = await Task.FromResult(item);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The `async` keyword makes the `Task` instance transparent to the method and automatically wraps the return value for you, in the same way that the `yield` statement rewrites a method to turn it into an iterator.

Comment: In this case, `async` isn't involved at all. It's `await` that instructs the compiler to asynchronously await for a task to finish, then return its result. The result from `await Task.FromResult(item)` is `item`. In fact, you could have written `return item` as your method doesn't do anything asynchronously

Comment: Also note that `async` simply tells the compiler to do `await` magic. If only the last call in your method is asynchronous, there's no need to await for the result, you can simply return the task.Assuming your method did something really asynchronous like an HTTP call, you could write `return httpClient.GetStringAsync(..);` and remove the `async` keyword completely.

Comment: Simply speaking, `await` equals `return someTask; return someTask.Result;`. Compiler makes the magic that code resume from the first return.

Comment: Please define 'doesn't work'. Have you looked at the error message? It's pretty descriptive. I'll bet it reads `Cannot convert Task<WorkItem> to Task<Task<WorkItem>>` or similar.

Comment: @ Bradly Smith : You could add answer so that I can accept your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line item = await Task.FromResult(item) is incorrect, it should actually just read:

```
return Task.FromResult(item);
```

As the method is marked as async, you return the task, and then whoever is calling CreateWorkItem() would do so using await, so the caller should look like:

```
WorkItem item = await CreateWorkItem(myWorkItem);
```

Or:

```
Task<WorkItem> itemTask = CreateWorkItem(myWorkItem);
item = await itemTask;
```